# How to split row with date range into multip rows by year

Tags: sql, split, date-range, group

The result of my simple SQL query

```
SELECT ID, STARDATE, ENDDATE
FROM A
INNER JOIN B ON A.ID = B.ID
    AND B.CONTRACTID = 572786
WHERE A.ISACTIVE = 1
```

is:

| ID | STARDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 394539 | 2024-03-01 | 2025-12-31 |
| 394540 | 2026-01-01 | 2026-12-31 |

But now I would like to convert/split the result into three rows by year (desired result):

| YEAR | ID | STARTDATE | ENDDATE |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 2024 | 394539 | 2024-03-01 | 2024-12-31 |
| 2025 | 394539 | 2025-01-01 | 2025-12-31 |
| 2026 | 394540 | 2026-01-01 | 2026-12-31 |

Is there anyone who can explain me how to tackle this in SQL?

Tried to find a solution on stackoverflow but I cant find any answers.

Answer (score 0):

We can solve your problem with the help of a *calendar* table.  In this case, the calendar table can maintain one record with start and end dates for each year which you want to appear in the report.

```
STARDATE   | ENDDATE
2024-01-01 | 2024-12-31
2025-01-01 | 2025-12-31
2026-01-01 | 2026-12-31
```

Here is the query you may use:

```sql
SELECT YEAR(C.STARDATE) AS YEAR, A.ID, A.STARDATE, A.ENDDATE
FROM CALENDAR C
LEFT JOIN A
    ON A.STARDATE <= C.ENDDATE AND A.ENDDATE >= C.STARDATE
INNER JOIN B
    ON B.ID = A.ID
WHERE
    A.ISACTIVE = 1 AND
    B.CONTRACTID = 572786;
```

Note that depending on your database, it might not have a `YEAR()` function to extract the year from a date.  The syntax might have to change in the first line of my query.